# clearInterval doesn't terminate

Tags: javascript

This is a auto tag script I am working on. It can be implemented on a 9gag post.(http://9gag.com/gag/*)

```
var division1 = ["@haxxorsid10 @haxxorsid11 @haxxorsid12", "@haxxorsid0"];
var i = 1;

window.onkeydown = function(e){

  if(e.keyCode == 113){ 
    document.getElementsByClassName("post-text-area")[0].value = division1[0];
    document.getElementsByClassName("cmnt-btn")[0].click();


var repeat = setInterval(function start(){
if(i == division1.length - 1)
    clearInterval(repeat);
document.getElementsByClassName("reply")[0].click();
document.getElementsByClassName("post-text-area")[1].value = division1[i];
document.getElementsByClassName("cmnt-btn")[1].click(); 
i++;
  },2000);}};
```

Problem is even after all elements of division1 are commented, it continues commenting `undefined`in comments. It seems clearInterval is never executed.

Comment: What does your config.log() say about i and division1.length in the interval?

Comment: why don't you use `setTimeout`?

Comment: @DanielA.White well I don't want to use setTimeout...but anyways I solved the problem just by adding curly braces...

Answer (score 0):

Firs time click `i=1` then 2nd time click it will count `i=2`.So the if condition not passing.so i was reset the `i` value at the time of clearinterval .So each time of you click count will restarted.

And also you are not adding ah brackets`if{}` with in a if condition.

```js
var division1 = ["@haxxorsid10 @haxxorsid11 @haxxorsid12", "@haxxorsid0"];
var i = 1;

window.onkeydown = function(e){

  if(e.keyCode == 113){ 
  

var repeat = setInterval(function start(){
  
 
if(i == division1.length - 1){
    clearInterval(repeat);
  i=0;//its will restart the count 2 time click
console.log('stop');
  }
  else{
  console.log('loop run')
  }
i++;
  },2000);}};
```

Answer (score -3):

Well, problem was solved just by applying curly braces around if.

```
if(i == division1.length - 1){
    clearInterval(repeat);
}
```

It solved the problem, but why curly braces worked out...

Comment: Instead of replying to your own question, you should have edited you question above with a solution.

Comment: @sam well I am new...but I believe, answering your own question is the correct way

Comment: You can always edit your question and modify it with solution in the end. That's what I was talking about

Comment: @sam Yes it is possible...but I am saying that it's better to post it as a answer. That's why stackoverflow has provided option to answer your own question!!! EOD.